# Unable to import in Android Studio: Cannot resolve symbol

Tags: java, android

I have a multi-modular project and I want to import those modules to use their classes in another module's class but when I try to import it in a new class, it can't seem to find the module and shows the error: Cannot resolve symbol 'module_name':

`import com.package.name.module_name // Cannot resolve symbol 'module_name'`

What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

I found my way around it!

1. Right Click on the module you want to import other modules in the Project pane and click Open Module Settings.
2. Go to Dependencies tab.
3. Add the little '+' icon at the bottom or press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>.
4. Select Module Dependency.